# Does this support Anchors shared between Hololens and mobile yet?

Tags: azure-spatial-anchors

Does Azure Spatial Anchors support sharing anchors between Hololens and mobile devices?  Obviously, Hololens has advanced spatial mapping and mobile devices only do planes at the moment, so there's quite a big difference.  I went through the tutorial projects and it wasn't clear that if I placed a Hololens anchor it would be accessible from mobile and vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

Yes the anchors can be shared. You can create them on any platform and they will be  persisted and available for any of the other supported ones. This tutorial illustrates how to do this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/spatial-anchors/tutorials/tutorial-share-anchors-across-devices